# Map (with operation) Stream java 8, nestedList

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm looking for `minimumlistPerValueOld` working translate to `minimumlistPerValueNew` in the method `getOptimizedTreeNodeResample(TreeNodeResample in, List<Integer> listSampleRateFinal)`

```
/*I need to find the list that by adding it to the nested list,
  the minimum number of operations required*/

  private static TreeNodeResample getOptimizedTreeNodeResample(TreeNodeResample in, List<Integer> listSampleRateFinal) {
    TreeNodeResample out = new TreeNodeResample(null);

    listSampleRateFinal.forEach(sampleRateFinal -> {
      List<List<NodeResample>> nestedListPerValue = getFilteredNestedListsValue(in, sampleRateFinal);
      Long lastMinimum = Long.MAX_VALUE;
      List<NodeResample> minimumlistPerValue = null;

      for (List<NodeResample> listPerValue : nestedListPerValue) {

        Long accumulator = addCalc(out.getNestedListsValue(), listPerValue)
            .stream()
            .map(nodeResample -> (long) nodeResample.getNumResampleOperations())
            .mapToLong(Long::longValue).sum();

        if (accumulator < lastMinimum) {
          lastMinimum = accumulator;
          minimumlistPerValue = listPerValue;
        }
      }

      out.addListValue(minimumlistPerValue);
    });
    return out;
  }
```

I believe I need to map `listPerValue`, as you can see `listPerValue` is the type `List<NodeResample>`

```
listPerValue ->  {
    TreeNodeResample temp = new TreeNodeResample(null);
    temp.setNestedListsValue(out.getNestedListsValue());
    temp.addListValue(listPerValue);
    return temp.getListNodes();// return List<TreeNodeResample> type
}
```

Or map (to the same object type)

```
listPerValue ->  {
    TreeNodeResample temp = new TreeNodeResample(null);
    temp.setNestedListsValue(out.getNestedListsValue());
    temp.addListValue(listPerValue);

    List<NodeResample> childsValues = temp.getListNodes()
    .stream()
    .map(node -> node.getValue())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return childsValues;// return List<NodeResample> type

}
```

**The complete `TreeNodeResample` class**:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class TreeNodeResample {

  TreeNodeResample parent;
  List<TreeNodeResample> children;
  NodeResample value;

  public TreeNodeResample(TreeNodeResample parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
    children = new ArrayList<>();
  }

  public TreeNodeResample(TreeNodeResample parent, NodeResample value) {
    this.parent = parent;
    children = new ArrayList<>();
    this.value = value;
  }

  public void addChild(TreeNodeResample node) {
    if (node != null && node.getValue() != null) {//REVIEW (node.getValue() != null) is needed?
      if (children.stream().noneMatch(child -> Objects.equals(child.getValue(), node.getValue()))) {
        children.add(node);
      }
    }
  }

  public TreeNodeResample getParent() {
    return parent;
  }

  public void cleanChildren() {
    children = new ArrayList<>();
  }

  public int getChildrenCount() {
    return children.size();
  }

  public TreeNodeResample getChildrenAt(int position) {
    if (children.size() > position && position > -1) {
      return children.get(position);
    }
    return null;
  }

  public List<TreeNodeResample> getChildren() {
    return children;
  }

  public NodeResample getValue() {
    return value;
  }

  public boolean isLeaf() {
    return (children.isEmpty());
  }

  public List<TreeNodeResample> getLeafs() {
    return getLeafs(this);
  }

  public void addListValue(List<NodeResample> listValue) {
    addListValue(this, listValue);
  }

  public TreeNodeResample getNode(NodeResample value) {
    return getNode(this, value);
  }

  public List<NodeResample> getListValues() {
    return getListNodes().stream().map(node -> node.getValue()).collect(Collectors.toList());
  }

  public List<TreeNodeResample> getListNodes() {
    List<TreeNodeResample> listNodes = new ArrayList<>();
    getListNodes(this, listNodes);
    return listNodes;
  }

  public List<List<NodeResample>> getNestedListsValue() {
    return getNestedListsValue(this);
  }

  public void setNestedListsValue(List<List<NodeResample>> nestedListsValue) {
    setNestedListsValue(this, nestedListsValue);
  }

  public List<List<NodeResample>> getFilteredNestedListsValue(int sampleRateTarget) {
    return getFilteredNestedListsValue(this, sampleRateTarget);
  }

  public TreeNodeResample getOptimizedTreeNodeResample(List<Integer> listSampleRateFinal) {
    return getOptimizedTreeNodeResample(this, listSampleRateFinal);
  }

  public static void addListValue(TreeNodeResample parent, List<NodeResample> listValue) {
    if (listValue != null) {
      TreeNodeResample node = parent;
      for (NodeResample child : listValue) {
        node = getNode(node, child);
      }
    }
  }

  public static TreeNodeResample getNode(TreeNodeResample parent, NodeResample value) {
    if (parent != null) {//REVIEW (value != null) is needed?
      TreeNodeResample node = parent.getChildren().stream()
          .filter(child -> child != null)
          .filter(child -> Objects.equals(child.getValue(), value))
          .findAny().orElse(null);
      if (node != null) {
        return node;
      }
      node = new TreeNodeResample(parent, value);
      parent.addChild(node);
      return node;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  public static List<TreeNodeResample> getListNodes(TreeNodeResample parent) {
    List<TreeNodeResample> listNodes = new ArrayList<>();
    getListNodes(parent, listNodes);
    return listNodes;
  }

  public static void getListNodes(TreeNodeResample parent, List<TreeNodeResample> listNodes) {
    if (parent != null) {
      listNodes.add(parent);
      parent.getChildren().forEach(child -> getListNodes(child, listNodes));
    }
  }

  public static List<List<NodeResample>> getNestedListsValue(TreeNodeResample parent) {
    List<TreeNodeResample> listLeafs = getLeafs(parent);
    List<List<NodeResample>> nestedListsValues = listLeafs.stream()
        .map(leaf -> getParentsListValue(leaf))
        .peek(listNodeResample -> {
          //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(listNodeResample.toArray()) + System.lineSeparator() + System.lineSeparator());
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return nestedListsValues;
  }

  public static void setNestedListsValue(TreeNodeResample parent, List<List<NodeResample>> nestedListsValue) {
    parent.cleanChildren();
    nestedListsValue.stream()
        .forEachOrdered(listValue -> {
          addListValue(parent, listValue);
        });
  }

  public static List<NodeResample> getParentsListValue(TreeNodeResample leaf) {
    List<NodeResample> listValue = new ArrayList<>();
    if (leaf != null) {
      listValue.add(leaf.getValue());
      TreeNodeResample node = leaf.getParent();
      while (node != null && node.getValue() != null) {
        listValue.add(0, node.getValue());
        node = node.getParent();
      }
    }
    return listValue;
  }

  public static List<List<NodeResample>> getFilteredNestedListsValue(TreeNodeResample parent, int sampleRateTarget) {
    List<TreeNodeResample> listNodes = getListNodes(parent)
        .stream()
        .filter(treeNodeResample -> treeNodeResample.getValue() != null)
        .filter(treeNodeResample -> treeNodeResample.getValue().getSampleRateTarget() == sampleRateTarget)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

    List<List<NodeResample>> nestedListsValues = listNodes.stream()
        .map(node -> getParentsListValue(node))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return nestedListsValues;
  }

  private static TreeNodeResample getOptimizedTreeNodeResample(TreeNodeResample in, List<Integer> listSampleRateFinal) {
    TreeNodeResample out = new TreeNodeResample(null);

    listSampleRateFinal.forEach(sampleRateFinal -> {
      List<List<NodeResample>> nestedListPerValue = getFilteredNestedListsValue(in, sampleRateFinal);
      Long lastMinimum = Long.MAX_VALUE;
      List<NodeResample> minimumlistPerValue = null;

      for (List<NodeResample> listPerValue : nestedListPerValue) {

        Long accumulator = addCalc(out.getNestedListsValue(), listPerValue)
            .stream()
            .map(nodeResample -> (long) nodeResample.getNumResampleOperations())
            .mapToLong(Long::longValue).sum();

        if (accumulator < lastMinimum) {
          lastMinimum = accumulator;
          minimumlistPerValue = listPerValue;
        }
      }

      out.addListValue(minimumlistPerValue);
    });
    return out;
  }

  private static List<NodeResample> addCalc(List<List<NodeResample>> nestednestedListValue, List<NodeResample> listPerValue) {
    TreeNodeResample temp = new TreeNodeResample(null);
    temp.setNestedListsValue(nestednestedListValue);
    temp.addListValue(listPerValue);
    return temp.getListNodes().stream()
        .map(node -> node.getValue())
        .filter(nodeResample -> nodeResample != null)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
  }

  public static List<TreeNodeResample> getLeafs(TreeNodeResample parent) {
    List<TreeNodeResample> listLeafs = new ArrayList<>();
    getLeafs(parent, listLeafs);
    return listLeafs;
  }

  private static void getLeafs(TreeNodeResample parent, List<TreeNodeResample> listLeafs) {
    if (parent != null && listLeafs != null) {
      if (parent.isLeaf()) {
        listLeafs.add(parent);
      } else {
        parent.getChildren().forEach(child -> getLeafs(child, listLeafs));
      }
    }
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "TreeNodeResample{" + "value=" + value + '}';
  }

  public static void tempPrintNested(List<List<NodeResample>> nestedListNodeResample) {
    System.out.println("  List<List<NodeResample>> nestedListNodeResample = Arrays.asList(");
    for (int o = 0; o < nestedListNodeResample.size(); o++) {
      List<NodeResample> listNodeResample = nestedListNodeResample.get(o);
      System.out.println("    Arrays.asList(");

      for (int i = 0; i < listNodeResample.size(); i++) {
        NodeResample nodeResample = listNodeResample.get(i);
        if (nodeResample != null) {
          System.out.print("      " + nodeResample.getCreator());
          if (i < listNodeResample.size() - 1) {
            System.out.println(",");
          } else {
            System.out.println("\n    )");
          }
        }
      }

      if (o < nestedListNodeResample.size() - 1) {
        System.out.println("    ,");
      }
    }
    System.out.println("  );");
  }

}
```

**The another `NodeResample` class**

```
public class NodeResample {

  private int incrementL;
  private int decrementM;
  private int sampleRateSource;
  private int sampleRateTarget;
  private double maxPassFreq;
  private Integer filterSize;
  private Integer numResampleOperations;

  public NodeResample(int incrementL, int decrementM, int sampleRateSource, int sampleRateTarget, double maxPassFreq, Integer filterSize, Integer numResampleOperations) {
    this.incrementL = incrementL;
    this.decrementM = decrementM;
    this.sampleRateSource = sampleRateSource;
    this.sampleRateTarget = sampleRateTarget;
    this.maxPassFreq = maxPassFreq;
    this.filterSize = filterSize;
    this.numResampleOperations = numResampleOperations;
  }

  public int getIncrementL() {
    return incrementL;
  }

  public void setIncrementL(int incrementL) {
    this.incrementL = incrementL;
  }

  public int getDecrementM() {
    return decrementM;
  }

  public void setDecrementM(int decrementM) {
    this.decrementM = decrementM;
  }

  public int getSampleRateSource() {
    return sampleRateSource;
  }

  public void setSampleRateSource(int sampleRateSource) {
    this.sampleRateSource = sampleRateSource;
  }

  public int getSampleRateTarget() {
    return sampleRateTarget;
  }

  public void setSampleRateTarget(int sampleRateTarget) {
    this.sampleRateTarget = sampleRateTarget;
  }

  public double getMaxPassFreq() {
    return maxPassFreq;
  }

  public void setMaxPassFreq(double maxPassFreq) {
    this.maxPassFreq = maxPassFreq;
  }

  public Integer getFilterSize() {
    return filterSize;
  }

  public void setFilterSize(Integer filterSize) {
    this.filterSize = filterSize;
  }

  public Integer getNumResampleOperations() {
    return numResampleOperations;
  }

  public void setNumResampleOperations(Integer numResampleOperations) {
    this.numResampleOperations = numResampleOperations;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "NodeResample{" + "L=" + incrementL + ", M=" + decrementM
        + ", Source=" + sampleRateSource + ", Target=" + sampleRateTarget
        + ", filterSize=" + filterSize + ", numResampleOperations=" + numResampleOperations 
        + "}   ";
  }

  public String getCreator() {
    return "new NodeResample(" + incrementL + "," + decrementM + "," + sampleRateSource + "," + sampleRateTarget + "," + "0.0" + "," + filterSize + "," + numResampleOperations
        + ")";
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 3;
    return hash;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
      return true;
    }
    if (obj == null) {
      return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
      return false;
    }
    final NodeResample other = (NodeResample) obj;
    if (this.incrementL != other.incrementL) {
      return false;
    }
    if (this.decrementM != other.decrementM) {
      return false;
    }
    if (this.sampleRateSource != other.sampleRateSource) {
      return false;
    }
    if (this.sampleRateTarget != other.sampleRateTarget) {
      return false;
    }
    if (!Objects.equals(this.filterSize, other.filterSize)) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

}
```

I want to translate using Java Streams

But, I'm frustrated...

```
  List<NodeResample> minimumlistPerValueNew = nestedListPerValue.stream()
      .min(
          Comparator.comparingLong(map(listPerValue -> {
            TreeNodeResample temp = new TreeNodeResample(null);
            temp.setNestedListsValue(out.getNestedListsValue());
            temp.addListValue(listPerValue);
            return temp.getListNodes();
          })
              //.map(node -> node::getValue)
              .filter(nodeResample -> nodeResample != null)
              .mapToLong(NodeResample::getNumResampleOperations).sum())
      )
      .orElse(Collections.emptyList());
```

**RESUMED SITUATION**

```
public CustomObject wrapperMethod(List<CustomObject> listCustomObjects) {
  Long lastMinimum = Long.MAX_VALUE;
  CustomObject minCustomObject;
  for (CustomObject customObject : listCustomObjects) {
    Long returnedValue = anyMethodReturningLong(customObject);
    if (returnedValue < lastMinimum) {
      lastMinimum = returnedValue;
      minCustomObject = customObject;
    }
  }
  return minCustomObject;
}
```

Comment: Too many segments that are not self-understood. e.g. `.getListNodes()` , `out.getNestedListsValue()` ... Can you share the POJOs and the signature of the methods used in here as well?

Comment: Just from the looks of it and I might be over-simplifying things, looks like this `List<NodeResample> minimumlistPerValueNew = nestedListPerValue.stream()
                .min(Comparator.comparingLong(a -> a.stream()
                        .map(node -> node.getValue())
                        .stream()
                        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                        .map(nodeResample -> (long) nodeResample.getNumResampleOperations())
                        .mapToLong(Long::longValue)
                        .sum()))
                .orElse(Collections.emptyList());`

Comment: While you're editing code to share it on SO, there is an inconsistency in the code that you might be able to compile and the code that you've shared in the question which doesn't compile. Might want to fix that to mark the question clear.

Comment: please Check **RESUMED SITUATION**

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Stream.reduce()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/reduction.html#reduce) also for your problem.

What I understand from your problem is that there is a nestedList and out of those inner Lists you want to return the list which matches your *minimum criteria*. 
For e.g let say we have nested list like this `[[1,2,4],[5,6,7,8,9,10],[11,12]]` and now you want return the list with smallest **list.size()**. Try below code :

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
public class Main
{
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<List<Integer>> nestedList = Arrays.asList(
      Arrays.asList(1,2,4), 
      Arrays.asList(5,6,7,8,9,2,5), 
      Arrays.asList(10,11,12,13,0));
      Optional<List<Integer>> oplist = nestedList.stream()
      .reduce((list1, list2) -> list1.size() < list2.size() ? list1 : list2);
      oplist.ifPresent(System.out::println); 
}
}
```

Output : [1,2,4]

Hope you get the idea behind the approach. Now you can try comparison check inside **reduce** method and check if it works for you.

**Solution for RESUMED SITUATION**

```
//Using .reduce() method 

Optional<CustomObject> minCustomObjectList = listCustomObjects.stream()
            .reduce((lastMinimum, returnedValue) -> anyMethodReturningLong(returnedValue) < anyMethodReturningLong(lastMinimum) ? returnedValue : lastMinimum);
minCustomObjectList.ifPresent(e -> System.out.println("Minimum Object using reduce method "+e.toString()));

//Using .min() method

CustomObject minCustomObject = listCustomObjects.stream()
            .min(Comparator.comparingLong(e -> anyMethodReturningLong(e))).get();
System.out.printf("Minimum Object using min method"+minCustomObject.toString());
```

Comment: please Check **RESUMED SITUATION**

Comment: @Anita check now.

Comment: Very, Very Thank you. I appreciate your time and response very much. I will test tomorrow (Unfortunately I can't test now, because my main code was changed), But like looks good solution.